# List lazy evaluation in Haskell

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation

I made simple assumptions below to understand list lazy evaluation in Haskell,

```
head [1, 2]                -- expr1
head [1 .. 2]              -- expr2
head [1 ..]                -- expr3

head . (1 :) $ []          -- eval1
head . (1 :) . (2 :) $ []  -- eval2
```

I suppose that `expr3` would be lazily evaluated like `eval1`, how about `expr1` and `expr2`?

Generally speaking,

- is lazy evaluation in Haskell a technique on both compile and run time?
- where is it said good for efficiency but hard to reason, on time, space complexity or program logic?

Comment: I can’t understand what you are asking. Looks like you are trying to reason about evaluation of expressions, but I have no idea what you are talking about in your examples. The keyword to learn more at Google is “WHNF”.

Comment: If someone tried to answer your question directly then the answer would be: “None of the expressions as they are written in your example are ever evaluated”.

Comment: Do you mean `head [1,2]` is compiled to `1` directly?

Comment: This question doesn’t make any sense as until the value is forced (e.g. your code performs IO with the value) nothing is evaluated. What `main = print $ head [1 ..]` will be compiled two is a question of optimisations used, it might as well be compiled to “print 1”. Also it is slightly difficult to reason about built-in constructs like `[a..b]` lists. If you had infinite lists implemented by yourself you would see the terms and you would be able to perform reductions by hands until you get the value you need. Again, WHNF is the key.

Comment: Now I see your point. Thanks for referring to `WHNF`. Are `weak head normal form` and `lazy evaluation` orthogonal topics?

Comment: I think that what you mean by “lazy evaluation” is not orthogonal. Actually WHNF, or, to be more precise, the combination of evaluation strategy “reduce everything to WHNF” and the idea of keeping expressions in “thunks” is how lazy evaluation is implemented.

Answer (score 6):

The term "lazy evaluation" is used in many ways.

1. Lazy evaluation is a semantics; it says something about which expressions evaluate to which values. (I admit that there are some details missing from the semantics, though!)
2. Lazy evaluation is an implementation strategy; it gives a way to "run" lambda calculus terms that conforms to the above-mentioned semantics, and uses sharing to improve on the time and memory usage of the more obvious "call-by-name" implementation strategy.
3. And you are using it in yet a third way, I think.

In the remainder, I will use "lazy evaluation" for the implementation strategy and "non-strict semantics" for the semantics.

> I suppose that `expr3` would be lazily evaluated like `eval1`, how about `expr1` and `expr2`?

A non-strict semantics dictates that evaluation of all five terms should terminate and produce the value `1`, so any conforming implementation will behave in that way. Lazy evaluation will do this in about the same amount of space and time for each expression. I expect that GHC would choose lazy evaluation if you forced any of these five terms, though with optimizations on it may perform the evaluation at compile-time. You could check this yourself by passing it the `-ddump-simpl` flag, if you were very interested.

> Is lazy evaluation in Haskell a technic on both compile and run time?

Hopefully the discussion above clarifies this question already. Non-strict semantics describe a particular connection between the compile-time and run-time (that is, the compiler must produce a program whose runtime behavior produces the values the semantics specifies). Lazy evaluation is a particular implementation strategy for producing a program that conforms to the semantics. GHC sometimes uses lazy evaluation in its programs, but sometimes uses other implementation strategies; however, it conforms to a non-strict semantics. (If you find a place where it doesn't, that's a bug!)

> Where is it said good for efficiency but hard to reason, on time, space complexity or program logic?

Non-strict semantics generally don't say anything about how much time or space is used during a computation, so if you want to reason about that, you need entirely different techniques. Even if you decide to restrict your reasoning to programs implemented with lazy evaluation, things can be difficult. Thinking about an expression like `[1..]`: how much space does this use? This question cannot be answered in a vacuum; the fundamental idea of lazy evaluation is to give the consumer of a value control over how much of the value is constructed. So without seeing what the program *does* with the expression `[1..]`, we can't know much. It might throw the value away, in which case almost no space is used; or it might walk down the list, in which case a constant amount of space is used; or it might traverse the list twice at different times, in which case unbounded space is used; or it might do a million other things with other space requirements.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I'm wondering if I could find a Haskell vocabulary including its academic terms and relevant industrial jargon.

Comment: @sof Depending on your interests, you might like "The Implementation of Functional Languages", "The Spineless Tagless G-Machine", or "Types and Programming Languages". Of course there is also the Haskell wiki, which has less depth, rigor, and direction, but is also immediately available and quite approachable.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing special about lists. They are simply recursive datatypes:

```
data [a] = a : [a] | []
```

Now when you use `[1 .. 2]`, that is **not** turned into a list `(1:(2:[]))` directly!, it is stored as the expression `[1 .. 2]`.

Now `head` is defined as:

```
head :: [a] -> a
head (x:_) = x
```

If you call `head [1 .. 2]`, into a `main` (and thus Haskell is somehow forced to evaluate it), it will see `[1 .. 2]` is not a datastructure, but an unresolved expression, it will resolve the expression a bit:

```
[1 .. 2] to (1:[(succ 1) .. 2])
```

And thus now one reads:

```
head (1:[(succ 1) .. 2])
```

(note that the tail is still an expression), but since `head` is only interested in - well - the "head" it will return `1`. Note that if the `head` was for instance `1+2`, it wouldn't evaluate this to `3` immediately either.

Furthermore if you simply call `head [1 .. 2]` the expression will **not be evaluated** automatically, it is only if you want for instance to display the result, Haskell will do an effort to calculate it.

Depending on the compiler-implementation, the compiler can do an effort at compile time to propagate constants (literals) and perform operations on them, but since a compiler should always follow the standard of execution, the semantics remain the same.

Comment: I should have better stated something that I typed the `head ..` expressions in `GHCi`  or abstracted them from `main = do print $ head ...` to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Well in ghci, it will - more or less - place a implicit `print $` in front, en thus evaluate until it can print the result.

Answer (score 2):

To complete other answers, you can check how lazy evaluation work with the `:sprint` command in ghci:

```
Prelude> let xs = [1..10] :: [Int]
Prelude> :sprint xs
xs = _
Prelude> head xs
1
Prelude> :sprint xs
xs = 1 : _
Prelude> take 3 xs
[1,2,3]
Prelude> :sprint xs
xs = 1 : 2 : 3 : _
Prelude> length xs
10
Prelude> :sprint xs
xs = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```